# why does my asp.net page not using my c# method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i have a problem with my project. When I submit a creditcardnumber the program should normally jump into my servervalidation, execute the commands from my if instruction and jump into both bool methods but the program just went through the if instruction and jumps into the submitbutton method to show the result. What did I do wrong?

here the code for the server:

```
protected void SubmitMidtermBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnMidtermInfoCollected();        
}       

public void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{     
    if (CardType(args.Value, CreditCardType.Text) && IsCreditCardValid(args.Value))
    {
        args.IsValid=true;
    }
    else
    {
        args.IsValid=false;
    }
}

public bool CardType(string cardNumber, string cardType)
{
    if (cardType.Equals("VISA"))
    {
        if (cardNumber.Length == 14 || cardNumber.Length == 16 &&
            (cardNumber.StartsWith("4")))
        {
            return true;
        }           
    }
    if (cardType.Equals("Mastercard"))
    {
        if ( cardNumber.Length == 16 &&
             cardNumber.StartsWith("51") ||
             cardNumber.StartsWith("52") ||
             cardNumber.StartsWith("53") ||
             cardNumber.StartsWith("54") ||
             cardNumber.StartsWith("55"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (cardType.Equals("AmericanExpress"))
    {
        if (cardNumber.Length == 15 &&
            cardNumber.StartsWith("34") ||
            cardNumber.StartsWith("37"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (cardType.Equals("Discover"))
    {
        if (cardNumber.Length == 16 &&
            cardNumber.StartsWith("601"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public bool IsCreditCardValid(string cardNumber)
{        
    int i;
    StringBuilder cleanNumber = new StringBuilder();

    for (i = cleanNumber.Length + 1; i <= 16; i++)
        cleanNumber.Insert(0, "0");

    int multiplier, digit, sum, total = 0;
    string number = cleanNumber.ToString();

    for (i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
    {
        multiplier = 1 + (i % 2);
        digit = int.Parse(number.Substring(i - 1, 1));
        sum = digit * multiplier;
        if (sum > 9)
            sum -= 9;
        total += sum;
    }

    return (total % 10 == 0);
}
```

*this thing don't catch the last closing tag that should be at this place*

at this point the server validation should be activated:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CreditcardValidation"
    ControlToValidate="CreditCardNumber"
    OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
    ErrorMessage=""
    runat="server" Display="Dynamic">
        <div class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a valid creditcard number</div>
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

can somebody please help me with that?

Comment: I doubt you'll get much help until you narrow down your problem. Very few people will read all that code.

Comment: okay i just shorted it to the method that is not really working.

Comment: Don't you need a manual check to trigger custom server validation like this? `if( !Page.IsValid ){ return; }` in your button event handler.

Comment: Check your operator precedence as well. For clarity you probably want to add some brackets to ensure it's doing what you want. C# does short circuit evaluation - eg A and B, B won't be evaluated if A is false. Use this to your advantage.

Comment: For future reference use the debugger. Add a breakpoint, enable the locals window, and press F11 to analyze your code during run-time, line-by-line.

Comment: oh my lord thank you Tim, this was it everything is working now. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the page event [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

If you read carefully, you'll find that the event handler for click events fires before the implicit call to page.Validate(), which is the method that raises the server validation events.  When you click handler is called, the validation routines haven't gone off yet.

> If the request is a postback, control event handlers are called. After that, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the page. (There is an exception to this sequence: the handler for the event that caused validation is called after validation.)

If you want to fire page.Validate() earlier, just call it explicitly.

```
protected void SubmitMidtermBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.OnMidtermInfoCollected();
}
```